# What is the JavaScript idiom for skipping whitespace?

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

Given a string `s` and a current index `i`, what's the idiomatic way in JavaScript (Node) to skip over whitespace starting at that position? In C, this would be done by:

```
while (isspace(s[i]))
    i++;
```

One could more or less directly translate this into JavaScript using `charCodeAt`, but is there a better solution?

Comment: Skip over for what reason? Usually you just slap it with a regex that collapses all the spaces if you don't care about them.

Comment: What is the input and what is the expected output?

Comment: @tadman Parsing. Cannot mangle the string because some of the spaces in it are significant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the index of the string at that point and see if its trimmed value is the empty string:

```
while (s[i].trim() === '')
  i++;
```

Or with a RE:

```
while (/\s/.test(s[i]))
  i++;
```

If there isn't anything else in the loop, you could do it without the loop:

```
i += s.slice(i).match(/^\s*/)[0].length;
```

But depending on what exactly you're trying to do, there may well be an even better approach.

Comment: Skip any whitespace character, not just ' '. JavaScript doesn't have isspace; a regular expression literal could do the same job; are they considered as idiomatic in JavaScript as they are in Perl?

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for by "idiomatic", but they can be used quite concisely and are easy to understand, so I wouldn't have any issues using a RE.

Comment: @rwallace Yes, `while (/\s/.test(s[i])) i++` would be perfectly fine JS